# Corsair H115i + Asus Prime Z270-A + Corsair Crystal 460x: Fitting issues

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, case, cpu-cooler

I've got a problem with my current PC build. I'm building my first PC, and it was going alright so far, but I've just ran into a big problem.

I have a Corsair Crystal Series 460x case, and an Asus Prime Z270-A motherboard. I've got the motherboard in fine, CPU is in, and the radiator for the Corsair H115i cooler is in as well. However, I have found that the fan that's meant to mount under the radiator does not have enough room to fit, due to what looks like some sort of heat sink on the motherboard. Pictures below (can't embed yet, unfortunately)

[image: Full View of the motherboard]
[image: Close-up]

I'm wondering, what are my options? Is it possible to remove the heatsink without breaking or harming the motherboard? Do I need to get a new case? A new cooler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to get a new case or cooler. I wouldn't recommend removing the heatsink on the motherboard. It is somewhat aesthetic, but does offer passive cooling for the VRM and chipset. Unfortunately, this is just how it goes when building a computer. Next time, make sure to pay attention to the dimensions and clearance of every part so you'll know ahead of time if all parts are compatible.

Comment: Will do. Going to be getting a new cooler. The one that the first guy recommended was out of stock, so I was sold the H115i by another guy, who said that it would work. Turns out, it didn't, and because of that [expletive removed] I'm out almost $200 (after taxes) because their coolers are final sale (Yes, I am a bit bitter about it). Thankfully I've got a friend who's gonna buy it off me for $150, so it's not a total write-off, and I'll be able to afford the first cooler.

Thanks Jarvis :)